# Creating HTML element : assign value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am dynamically creating HTML parapgraphs, and I need them to have a value. What is the best way ?

```
// here, I tried to assign a value to the 'innerHTML' attribute. Doesn't work
$A.createComponent(
    "aura:html",
    {
        tag: "p",
        HTMLAttributes: {
            "class": "prestationName",
            "innerHTML": "prestationName goes here"
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aura:unescapedHtml for this purpose:

```
$A.createComponent(
    "aura:unescapedHtml",
    {
        value: "<p>prestationName goes here</p>"
    }
);
```

Make sure you escape any potentially dangerous characters like <, >, and &.